# Aggregate data grouping by two columns in Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have these data that I need to group by two columns and then sum up two other fields. 
Suppose the name for these four columns are:OS,device,view,click. I basically want to know the count for each OS and device, how many views they have and how many clicks it have.

```
(2,3346,1,)
(3,3953,1,1)
(25,4840,1,1)
(2,94840,1,1)
(14,0526,1,1)
(37,4864,1,)
(2,7353,1,)
```

This is what I have so far

```
A is data: OS,device,view,click

B = GROUP A BY (OS,device);

Result = FOREACH  B {
    GENERATE group AS OS,device, SUM(view) AS visits, SUM(click) AS clicks;};
dump Result;
```

This one won't work, error message is: Projected field [OS] does not exist in schema: group:tuple(OS:int,device:long),B:bag{:tuple(OS:int,device:long,view:int,click:int)}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which is tested, you are missing FLATTEN:

```
A = LOAD '/user/root/pig_data' using PigStorage(',') AS (OS, device, view, click);
B = GROUP A BY (OS, device);
RESULT = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (OS, device), SUM(A.view) as views, SUM(A.click) as clicks;
dump RESULT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `B` in your example instead of `J2` or `J3`, which may be in your actual code. Try:

```
B = GROUP A BY (OS, device);

Result = FOREACH B GENERATE
    group.OS AS OS:int,
    group.device AS device:long,
    SUM(B.view) AS visits:int,
    SUM(B.click) AS clicks:int;

dump Result;
```